# Is there a way to subtract 2 timestamps and get the result in 'hh:mm:ss' format in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to get the duration between two timestamps using

```sql
select timestamp1-timestamp2 as time_s
from table_name
```

but I'm getting result as:

```
00:00:06.070627
00:00:33.415313
00:00:51.293319
00:02:00.146453
00:02:25.600623
00:06:37.811005
00:28:27.698517
```

I don't want the values after '`.`'

I tried using

```
split_part(time_s, '.',1)
```

but it gave

```
6070627
33415313
51293319
120146453
145600623
397811005
1707698517
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: When subtracting `timestamp` fields, Redshift returns an `interval`. If you want to manipulate the display, you could cast it as a string and then split based on the '`.`'. Or, you might be able to use: `SUBSTRING((timestamp1-timestamp2)::TEXT, 1, 8)`

Comment: Hi, I made the specified changes but got this result '''29359837
6393879
38183881
60216227
53166284
23109156
35401769'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between two timestamps is an **INTERVAL**.

The basic problem that you are experiencing is that there is no standard way to display or return an Interval. For example:

- If you try your query in the web-based Redshift Query Editor, it will return NULL
- If you run it in your particular SQL Client, it is returning `00:00:06.070627`
- If you run it in DbVisualizer, it is returning `0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs`
- If you run it in DataGrip, it is returning `Invalid character data was found`

When you were attempting to extract a portion of the result to the left of the `.`, Redshift was confused because **it does not see the output the way it is displayed in your SQL Client**.

The best way to avoid your SQL Client from doing strange things to results is to **convert the answer to TEXT**:

```
SELECT (timestamp1 - timestamp2)::TEXT
```

This gives an answer like: `24 days 13:57:40.561373`

You can then manipulate it like a string:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART((timestamp1 - timestamp2)::TEXT, '.', 1)
```

This gives: `24 days 13:57:40`

**Bottom line:** When things look strange in SQL results, cast the result to TEXT or VARCHAR to see what the data *really* looks like.